# SliverAppBar with curved bottom in NestedScrollView - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to create a SliverAppBar with a curved bottom. So far I've been able to create this;
[My Design(SliverAppBar curved upwards)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TImDT.jpg). But what I want is the SliverAppBar to curve downwards, like this;
[Design with SliverAppBar curved downwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTmh.jpg). Is it really possible to achieve this with the ***shape*** parameter in SliverAppBar? And if so, how do we go about it? And how can I make the collapsible appBar not to shrink entirely - I want the background image to only reduce by half its original length and still be visible as a user scrolls upwards.

Comment: It seems other way round to me your background is rectangle and menu over it is curved on top

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SliverAppBar(
  pinned: true,
  expandedHeight: 200,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  bottom: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text('test'),
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
    ),
  ),
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(....
```

Use the bottom to add AppBar with Container with radius border.